# How to read text from an already open webpage using VBA

Tags: vba

I have made a macro to read text from a saved html page/file. I now need to make it more advance by reading an already open webpage. would really appreciate the help

Need to replace the line

```
URL = "file:///C:/test.html"
```

with something that will read an open webpage. I can make sure that there is only one tab open. I'm using the latest IE

```
Dim URL As String
Dim Data As String

URL = "file:///C:/test.html"

Dim ie As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate URL

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

Set ieDoc = ie.Document

Data = ieDoc.body.innerText
```

Comment: Is it not an option to actually specify the URL to get the data from?

Comment: What do you mean by `already open webpage`?

Comment: @OlleSjögren already open webpage = there is a webpage which open in the IE = webpage was opened in the browser before the macro was fired

Comment: @ChrisProsser i'm not at the liberty of calling a second instance of the webpage...i need to utilize the one which is already open

Comment: Then it is more than the URL code that you need to change. Your existing code appears to be opening a new instance of IE for a local html file. I'm not sure whether it is even possible to read activity from an existing browser session from VBA.

Comment: i agree. i need to change more. further, if we can't read from the existing instance of the browser, can i not save an open webpage and then read the html file the way i did the current code?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the title or url of the already open webpage you're looking for, then this code will let you control it

```
' Determine if a specific instance of IE is already open.
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
    For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
        my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
        my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

        'You can use my_title of my_url, whichever you want
        If my_title Like "Put your webpage title here" & "*" Then   'identify the existing web page
            Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get the currently running internet explorer (work atleast with IE9):

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWindow As Object
Dim objItem As Object

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
For Each objItem In objWindow
    If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*iexplore*") Then
        Set ie = objItem
    End If
Next objItem

MsgBox ie.Document.body.innertext
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' Add reference to 
' - Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' - Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation (Shell32)
' Find all running instances of IE and get web page Url
' Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx
' Useful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890(v=vs.85).aspx

Sub main()
    Dim browsers
    Set browsers = GetBrowsers

    Dim browser
    Dim url
    For Each browser In browsers
        url = browser.document.Location.href
        Debug.Print CStr(url)
    Next browser
End Sub

Public Function GetBrowsers() As Collection

    Dim browsers As New Collection
    Dim shellApp As Shell32.Shell
    Dim wnds As SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    Set shellApp = New Shell
    Set wnds = shellApp.Windows

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.WebBrowser
    Dim name

    For i = 1 To wnds.Count
        Set ie = wnds(i)
        If ie Is Nothing Then GoTo continue
        If UCase(ie.FullName) Like "*IEXPLORE.EXE" Then
            browsers.Add ie
        End If
continue:
    Next i

    Set GetBrowsers = browsers
    Set shellApp = Nothing
End Function
```