# vba won't click on hyperlink unless stepping through

Tags: vba

I'm working on a project for the company that I work for and am new to VBA. I am trying to log into a vendor's website and navigate to the price inquiry page.

I am able to login but after logging in I can't get VBA to click on the hyperlink that I want it to, unless I step through the code using F8. I've tried to pause at certain spots in the code but it still wont work.

I posted the portion of the code that is giving problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub getDurablePrices()
Dim IE As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "http://duraweb.durableusa.com/Acct%20Mgmt/Login.aspx"
IE.Visible = True
Do While IE.Busy
'nothing
Loop

IE.document.All("htmUserName").Value = "******"
IE.document.All("htmPwd").Value = "******"

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" Then
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

objElement.Click

'Code added as suggested.
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")

For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
    If hyper_link.innerText = "Customer Price Inquiry" Then
        hyper_link.Click
        Exit For

    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to click:

```
<a class="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTree_0" 
href="Customer/CustomerPriceInquiry.aspx" 
id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4">Customer Price Inquiry</a>
```

Comment: What happens if you put `DoEvents` after the click? Probably won't work, but worth trying.

Comment: Did you try 
 IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4").Click

Comment: I tried the DoEvents after the click and it still doesn't click. I also tried IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4").Click  and it works, only when I step through the code. When I run it normally it still doesn't click.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a timer - instead wait for the page to be finished loading with something like this:

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

...or as a single-line that I place after any "click" or other actions that causes a change on the page:

```
Debug.Print"Waiting, ";:Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState<>4:DoEvents:Loop:Debug.Print"Loaded."
```

---

### More Information:

- Mozilla : [**Document.readyState**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)
- Stack OVerflow : [**How to read text from an already open webpage using VBA**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21407340/8112776)

Comment: I went ahead and added the code for the readyState and Busy, as suggested, however it still is failing to click on the hyperlink. It still only clicks the hyperlink when I walk through the code or set a breakpoint to pause it.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the relevant section of html? (but no promises)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried after the second

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

To then do

```
IE.navigate Trim$(Split(Split(IE.document.body.innerHTML, "id=""ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4""")(0), "href =")(1))
```

This is assuming you can't do

```
IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4").Click
```

Or

```
Dim targetElement As Object

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetElement = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4")
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
Loop While targetElement Is Nothing
```

Comment: The IE.navigate Trim$(Split(Split(IE.document.body.innerHTML, "id=""ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4""")(0), "href =")(1)) doesn't work for me. But, when I put IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MenuTreet4").Click and step through the code it works. At full speed it doesn't click.

Comment: I get a run time error when I try the bottom idea, looping while is nothing. I'm new to VBA and am unsure exactly how to wrap the set targetelement inside of on Error Resume Next. Could you show how to do this?

Comment: I added the code and added the line targetElement.Click right after it. The error goes away but it still does not click unless I step through the code.

Comment: If you put STOP after Loop While... and before any click. Then inspect targetElement in the immediate window (Ctrl + G) - Does it have a value? I.e. did it actually set?

Comment: So what appears to happen when I set a break point before the click it shows that the targetElement is set correctly when I step through the code. When I just run it, it seems to be in an infinite loop, never setting the targetElement and never getting to the click. This was my first time using the immediate window. That helped see what was going on. Not sure why it loops infinitely.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest without more to go on I'm afraid. You might want to look into selenium basic and running your process through broswer automation. I find that is often helpful as you can have the browser side by side with the code window and try different things out to see what works and immediately see the effect.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help.